# how can I create a hidden text input box?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm writing a wtforms custom form that consists of

- multiple boolean check button / radio button
- and a hidden text input.
- if user clicks 'other' button, the textinput is enabled and user can manually write things
- if user un-clicks 'other' button, the textinput is disabled.

here's the widget function that draws this(for multiple checkboxes):

```
def select_multi_other_checkbox(field, ul_class='', **kwargs):
    """check wtforms.widgets.core to see what is going on"""
    kwargs.setdefault('type', 'checkbox')
    field_id = kwargs.pop('id', field.id)
    html = [u'<ul %s>' % html_params(id=field_id, class_=ul_class)]
    for value, label, checked in field.iter_choices():
        choice_id = u'%s-%s' % (field_id, value)
        options = dict(kwargs, name=field.name, value=value, id=choice_id)
        if checked:
            options['checked'] = 'checked'
        html.append(u'<li><input %s /> ' % html_params(**options))
        html.append(u'<label %s>%s</label></li>' % (html_params(**options), cgi.escape(text_type(label))))

    else:
        choice_id = u'%s-%s' %(field_id, u'other')
        options = dict(kwargs, name=field.name, value='', id = choice_id)
        options['type'] = 'text'
        html.append(u'<input %s > ' % (html_params(**options)))

    html.append(u'</ul>')
    cPickle.dump(html, open("htmltest.p", "wb"))
    return u''.join(html)
```

the part `html.append(u'<input %s > ' % (html_params(**options)))` is where textinput is added. (note that `options['type'] = 'text'` means `type="text"` attribute for `<input>` tag) The question is, How can I make hidden textinput (not `type="hidden"`) so that I can reveal it via jquery later?

Comment: Is there something against using the `disabled` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add styling that hides it:

```html
<input type="text" style="display:none" id="myhiddentextfield" />
```

then use jQuery to show it:

```js
$('#myhiddentextfield').show();
```

Comment: is there a chance that style attribute might somehow collide with css loaded for the page(I don't have one at the moment, though)?

Comment: @thkang: Sure, if you have a `input { display: block !important; }` then the element-level CSS will be ignored. But that'd be a stupid CSS rule that you won't normally see. :-)

Comment: @thkang: Note that *only* if there are `display: block !important` rules in the external sheet that apply to the input would this not work; you can always add `!important` to the local `style` attribute in that case. `!important` is usually a sign of incorrect design in any case.